# Jacobian for non-linear transformations

Tags: multivariable-calculus, jacobian

Say I have the following transformation

$$u = xy, v = \frac{y}{x}$$

for my double integral:

$$\int_{a}^{b} \int_{c}^{d} f(x,y)dxdy$$

To successfully transform the coordinates I need to know the Jacobian of the transformation. However, it is not linear and thus impossible to express by a matrix. How can I find the Jacobian then?

Comment: Not impossible, the Jacobian matrix need not be a linear transformation.

Comment: The Jacobian is just the matrix of partial derivatives, correct? I think that $\frac{2y}{x}$ will be your determinant.

Comment: @IgnacioRojas: The Jacobian matrix is always a linear transformation, it's a matrix. I think you meant to say that the original map for which we take the derivative of doesn't have to be linear.

Comment: @Faraad You're correct, that's what's I meant to say. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Jacobian is

$$ \frac{\partial (u,v)}{\partial (x,y)}
=  \left|\begin{matrix} \displaystyle\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} & \displaystyle\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \\
\displaystyle\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} & \displaystyle\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} \end{matrix}\right| 
= \left|\begin{matrix} y & x \\ \displaystyle -\frac{y}{x^2} & \displaystyle\frac{1}{x} \end{matrix}\right| 
= \frac{2y}{x} = 2v $$

The Jacobian is just a matrix of partial derivatives. It has nothing to do with whether the transformation itself is linear.